# MongoDB - Order by date of comments from posts objects; 1 collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection:

```
{
  _id - ObjectId
  "post_title": "first post",
  "post_date: 123456,
  "comments" [
    {
      "comment_title": "test",
      "comment_time": 123456
    },
    {
      "comment_title": "test2",
      "comment_time": 1234567
    }  
  ]  
},

{
  _id - ObjectId
  "post_title": "second post",
  "post_date: 1234567,
  "comments" [
    {
      "comment_title": "test3",
      "comment_time": 12345678
    },
    {
      "comment_title": "test4",
      "comment_time": 123456789
    }  
  ]  
}
```

Now, I want to get all the comments on order by descending regardless of posts. Just want to list down all the comments in descending order. I am not sure whether its possible using single MongoDB query or not therefore not putting anything as my attempts.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Could give an example of data you expect as the result?

Comment: you want to sort the comments subdocuments or the post documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need just comments list in time descending order

```
db.posts.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$comments"}, 
    {$project: { "title": "$comments.comment_title", "time": "$comments.comment_time"}}, 
    {$sort: { "time": -1 }}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort by descending `comment_time`, use the following aggregation :

```
db.device.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$comments"}, 
  {$sort: {"comments.comment_time":-1}}, 
  {$group: {_id:"$_id", comments: {$push:"$comments"}}}
]);
```

It performs :

- `$unwind` your comments array
- `$sort` `comments.comment_time` descending (-1)
- `$group` to rewind your array with the sorted values